# Unable to load dynamic library gettext.so and /usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib on MAC (Maverick)

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2

when I execute the phpUnit test I get these errors. How have I to solve them?

```
[31-May-2014 09:41:47 CET] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/gettext.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/gettext.so, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
```

Referenced from: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/gettext.so

Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0

```
[31-May-2014 09:41:47 CET] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function _() in /var/www/myproject/module/Base/config/module.config.php on line 44
```

thanks

Comment: Is gettext installed on your system? PHP should be configured using `--with-gettext=/path/to/gettext` option. You can see your configuration options using `php -i | grep Configure` command.

Comment: @foozy Yes it is installed but seems that php doesn't load it. The command suggested doesn't show the gettext module.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?